# background-image with a left and right, the repeat-x of center image makes the right image not show up

Tags: css

```
.news-header {
background-image: url(maureske_green_left.gif), url(maureske_green_body.gif),    url(maureske_green_right.gif);
background-position: left, center, right;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat;
height: 31px;
}
```

This works good but the repeat-x of `maureske_green_body.gif` makes maureske_green_right.gif to not show up.

Setting a `width` doesnt make the right image to show neither.

If I do `no-repeat` on the center image all images show up but of course theres a gap between all three. So how do I fix without making center image same width as webpage?

Thanks in advance!

Jarosław

Answer (score 0):

Top image layer is first in your css, so you need to reorder them this way:

```
background-image: url(maureske_green_left.gif), url(maureske_green_right.gif), url(maureske_green_body.gif);
```

In short version your new css will be:

```
.news-header {
    background: url(maureske_green_left.gif) no-repeat left top, 
        url(maureske_green_right.gif) no-repeat right top,
        url(maureske_green_body.gif) repeat center top;
    height: 31px;
}
```

Interesting article about multiple css backgrounds [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Comment: Ah! It was that easy?! I will accept your answer in 10 minutes